# Button position in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a inspiration post style:

[image]

So when I'm trying to make one I face some problem such as:

- button not rounded when I change window size
- social icons doesn't show
- I can't click social icons
- not responsive

code on codepen (https://codepen.io/youssefelmajbri/pen/eRjKoj):

```css
.media {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 550px;
  height: 151px;
}

.media-body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.thumb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#social-fb {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#social-tw {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#social-yt {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#social-rd {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 7%;
  margin-top: -30;
  margin-left: -10;
  background-color: #E91E63;
  color: white;
}

.img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h1 class="lead text-center">THis a text</h1>

            <hr>
            <p class="small"> that you'll remeber and don't forget if that you want to forget you'll not able to.</p>

          </div>
          <a class="thumb">


            <img src="http://img02.deviantart.net/712d/i/2015/231/3/e/flat_landscape_by_eocdesigns-d96dbbn.jpg">

            <i class="fa fa-facebook" id="social-fb"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" id="social-tw"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube" id="social-yt"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-reddit" id="social-rd"></i>
          </a>


        </div>
        <a href="Post.html"><button class="btn" id="btn" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post style image : http://imgur.com/a/XTakT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> button not rounded when I change window size

This is because you are using percentages to set button width/height. These percentages will be fractions of the parent element, so 8% of width and 7% of height will not necessarily be equal, and if the parent width/height changes, these sizes will as well. Use static values instead (px/em/rem, etc).

> social icons doesn't show

I would suggest placing these using absolute positioning. Surround the icons width a div, set this in div style:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
```

And add `position: relative` to parent element.

> I can't click social icons

Well there aren't any click events attached to them, you need to give them an `onclick` event or similar, or surround them with a styled, clickable component like `a href="..."` or `button`.

Additionally I would suggest using, `width` and `height` instead of `max-width` and `max-height` on the image, so as to remove that white space beneath it.